# How do I disable cookies on a website I deployed?

Tags: web, cookies, backend

I deployed a MERN app through heroku, then bought a domain name and connect it.

It is using 2 cookies, and I am not sure how I can disable cookies for now for all visitors because of the cookies policy.

I have zero code for configuring cookies in my application, yet there are two.

When I click on both of them, it says localstorage for both.

What can I do either in my code or heroku settings or DNS to get rid of the cookies?

Comment: There isn't enough information here to answer this question.  What are the cookies?  What code is setting them?  Please [edit] your question to add details.

Comment: @StephenOstermiller Hello, I editted and provided all detail I could. Please take a look! Thank you

Comment: Cookies don't get set magically. There has to be code that is doing it.  If they are localstorage, it is JavaScript that is doing it.

Comment: @StephenOstermiller I am using create-react-app. However, my search tells me CRA does not provide cookies automatically... I will look into this. Thank you